# Graphics bug with inline tag editing

Tags: bug, inline-tag-editor

I recently achieved 10k on a particular site and earned the "Access moderator tools" privilege, which includes *Inline tag editing*.

But whenever I go to use the "Edit tags" button on a post, some large scary black shapes materialise and then vanish immediately:

[image: cursor clicking on the "Edit tags" button which produces large black fuzzy squares that then quickly disappear]

This is quite unpleasant, so I probably won't use this feature unless it gets fixed.

---

The web browser I was using at the time was Opera, but the same bug (with slight variation) appears when I'm using any of theses:

- **Opera** v94.0.4606.38
- **Chrome** v108.0.5359.124
  - shapes appear and disappear quicker
- **Firefox** v108.0.1
  - shapes appear and disappear quicker
- **Safari** v14.1.2
  - shapes appear and disappear quicker
  - shapes are much shorter (vertically)

If relevant my computer is running **macOS Mojave** v10.14.6